How to get pytest to import different files with the same path?
I am working in a codebase with the following folder structure:
lambdas
|-lambda1
  |-core
  |-infrastructure
  ...
|-lambda2
  |-core
  |-infrastructure
  ...
...
tests
|-unit
  |-lambda1
    ...tests
  |-lambda2
    ...tests
  ...

Since the lambdas are all deployed independently, imports within each lambda are absolute and from the root, like so:
import core.domain.user

My issue arises when I am running tests with PyTest. When the tests for lambda1 are ran, sys.modules creates an entry for 'core' and maps it to the core module in lambda1:
{
...
'core': <module 'core' from '/Users/me/project/lambdas/lambda1/core/__init__.py'>
...
}

Then, when I want to import 'core' again when the lambda2 tests run, I get errors since the wrong core module is imported.
I have tried deleting this entry in conftest.py but that didn't solve the issue, I think since sys.path will also grab the wrong 'core' module depending on its order. I have tried altering sys.path in every test file and that seems to help but feels too much like a hack.
I think that moving the tests to be in the same directory as their lambda would help, but I want to explore options that don't alter the folder structure first.
Any ideas?

What are the errors you're getting when trying to import core again?

depends on how I have conftest.py configured, but something like this: ImportError: cannot import name 'entity' from 'core.domain.entities'

Are you deploying the lambda1 & lambda2 as packages?

they get deployed as AWS Lambda functions. honestly not sure of the internals of how the code is executed beyond that

It sounds like you're trying to use them as packages but when you import them you're not specifying which package.  Typically you would do import lambda1.core.domain.user to avoid the namespace collisions.

unfortunately I can't do that since each lambda gets deployed independently. there is no "lambda1" once it has been deployed

Do you understand the problem then?  You'll need to isolate the packages.  Python cannot differentiate between core vs core

I understand that is the problem. I was hoping someone had a solution that was outside of my knowledge

You can set up a pytest.fixture to import the module, or file that you want to test, with sys.modules patched with the correct module for core.
For example, to test a file api inside infrastructure which has many imports to core, define a fixture to give the patched import:
from unittest.mock import patch
import importlib
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def patched_api():
    with patch.dict(
        "sys.modules",
        {
            "core": importlib.import_module(
                "lambdas.identities_api.federation_anchors.core"
            ),
        },
    ):
        from lambdas.lambda1.infrastructure import api

        yield api

then test normally, but with an api with all the right imports, defined in the fixture:
def test_handle(patched_api, event, context):
    result = patched_api.handle(event, context)

    assert result["statusCode"] == http.HTTPStatus.NO_CONTENT

